# Error while recording with JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I set up `JMeter` and trying to record a test by logging into a website and browsing it.

**Issue is the next:**

I can log in to that site but, I can't browse the site as following error appears:

> JSONException: Error occurred during object input read.

Is there any solution for this? I haven't found any answer over web too.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are getting this error while recording and after login to your web application i.e. on the Homepage/landing page of the application right?

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Answer (score 2):

1. In majority of cases JMeter should print the relevant information into *jmeter.log* file.
2. Try clean session: delete browser's cache, cookies, etc.
3. You can try [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1528451-chrome-extension) instead of JMeter's proxy to see whether it resolves your issue